# Using the Gradle flavor in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors

I want to make an Android App with two different versions.

This is what I want to achieve

`Main Screen` calls a method in the Class named `Execute`

Now I want to have two different version of `Execute class`. Let's call the first one `Flavor1` and the second version as `Flavor2`. `Flavor1` will need the help of a library called `Test1`. Whereas the `Flavor2` Execute class will need the Help of library called `Test2`.

Now what I am trying to achieve is when I try to build the `Flavor1` then `Test 2` library should NOT be included in the `APK file`. And when I build the `Flavor2` then the Test1 library should NOT be included in `APK file`.

So this is the Scenario

```
Main Class --> Execute Class

Execute Class(Flavor1)-->Test1 Library

Execute Class(Flavor2)-->Test2 Library

Building Flavor1 should not contain Test2 Library

Building Flavor2 Should not contain Test1 Library
```

Is there any way to achieve this. Any Help would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined flavors appropriately you can have flavor specific implementations as following :-

say I have two different app-compat versions as per flavors

```
flavorOneImplementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
flavorTwoImplementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
```

Comment: Sorry, But one more question, Is it possible to build different flavors of a Library?

Comment: Include library in the different flavors project as above or build your library in different flavors?

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I build library of Different Flavors. But then how should I include them to the project. Only One flavor of library should be included in my app which is not going to have any flavors. But the other flavor of the library will be included in some other app as aar. I am including the library in the app (Before creating flavor) `implementation project(':libraryname')`. How can I add to include a specific flavor?

Comment: That is a great question. Never had to use it though. I suppose you can. I had earlier bookmarked this page which might help you : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration

Comment: Also this https://android.jlelse.eu/product-flavors-for-android-library-d3b2d240fca2

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look and try. Will update you soon.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks once again for the help. The links solved my problem.